# Display metabox values in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to add metabox with date in Wordpress. I used code from [this page](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/start-date-end-date-metabox-for-events-custom-post-types/). It works well, but I have a problem displaying the metabox values on page.

My loop:

```
<?php query_posts(array('post_type' => 'event' , 'posts_per_page' => 9999, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC' ));
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID); ?>

<div class="event">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <p>Date: <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_day', true);?>.<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_month', true);?>.<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_year', true);?></p>
    <p>Hour: <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_hour', true);?>:<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_minute', true);?></p>
    <?php the_content(''); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

I added custom post type 'event'. Values in metabox(date/location) have been saved, but it haven't displayed on page.

Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Hey you edited your post while i posted the answer at same time

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I have been edited, because I saw negligible fault in code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I have written incorrect meta_key.

For example:

Instead '_day' must be '_start_day' (for Start day) or '_end_day' (for End day)

Correct code for display metabox with Start Day:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_start_day', true);?>
```